# Why is the XPath not valid?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

The problem is that the XPath I get from Chrome is not correct or I do not know how to edit it so I can make it usable. I wanna parse it so i can get the results through a discord bot.

I did not try anything at all, I have no experience in using XPath so that is why I am here.

```
//*[@id="home"]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]
```

What should happen is(if the xpath path would work) that I get a result through a discord bot but the path is not correct.

> Could not store a value from path //* 
>    [@id="home"]/div/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2], Check that the path is valid!

Comment: which show the html code where you running the XPath then we can easily tell you the reason.

Comment: [html](http://prntscr.com/nvgw69) there u go

Comment: If u wanna see the html by yourself, this is the [page](https://panel.eclipsed.ro/profile/Wefx), i wanna get the 'Level' value from there(only the value, not the text too)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Xpath.

```
//table[@class='table bb']//tr[1]/td[2]/@text
```

Comment: Bot is ready!
Could not store a value from path //table[@class='table bb']//tr[1]/td[2], Check that the path is valid!

Comment: Could not store a value from path //table/*/tr[1]/td[2], Check that the path is valid! oof, same thing.

Comment: still the same, oof

Answer (score 0):

Use this xpath.

```
 //table[@class='table bb']//td[strong[.='Level']]/following-sibling::td
```

If you expecting value `33` from the xpath then you can use either

```
 //table[@class='table bb']//td[strong[.='Level']]/following-sibling::td/text()
```

or

```
  //table[@class='table bb']//td[strong[.='Level']]/following-sibling::td/@text
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Could not store a value from path //table[@class='table bb']//td[strong[.='Level']]/following-sibling::td, Check that the path is valid!  Also, i just wanna get the value, not the text too.

Comment: can you please share the line of code where you are using this xpath.

Comment: The thing is i am using something that automatically parses it, like a "maker" [here](https://pastebin.com/4uEsw5CN) is the code for the script